# setError popup not repositioning correctly after hitting back on soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

1) make 2 Edit Text fields close to the bottom of the screen, also a submit button (on submit have a setError called on the first field)

2) run the app, enter some text in both fields, hit submit

3) you should see the error popup in the correct position (as expected), click into the 2nd text field, then click back into the first text field, the error popup is off-position (it's either not aligned correctly or the arrow is flipped in the wrong direction). While the soft keyboard is up in this case you can also hit back to close the soft keyboard but the error popup is still off-positioned.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add this class to your source folder.

   public class ListenerEditText extends EditText {

   ```
   private KeyImeChange keyImeChangeListener;

   public ListenerEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public void setKeyImeChangeListener(KeyImeChange listener){
       keyImeChangeListener = listener;
   }

   public interface KeyImeChange {
       public void onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onKeyPreIme (int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
       if(keyImeChangeListener != null){
           keyImeChangeListener.onKeyIme(keyCode, event);
       }        
       return false;
   }
   ```

   }
2. In your XML file.

```html
<com.src.ListenerEditText
                                    android:id="@+id/password"
                                    style="@style/EditBoxStyle"
                                    android:ems="30"
                                    android:hint="*API Key"
                                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                                    android:maxLength="250"
                                    android:singleLine="true" 
                                </com.src.ListenerEditText>
```

3. Add action for edittext.

```html
password.setKeyImeChangeListener(new KeyImeChange() {
    
      @Override
      public void onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    
       if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        
         password.clearFocus();
    
       }
    
      }
     });
```